# How can I get Quarter to Date in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I'm having a hard time getting the quarter to date values from Hive SQL. 
How can I get the first day of the current quarter in Hive sql?

Table name: Orders

Fields: date, order_num, sales_num

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This seems to be the cleanest way**

```
with t as (select date '2016-08-27' as dt) 
select add_months(trunc(dt,'MM'),-(month(dt)-1)%3) from t
;
```

> 2016-07-01

---

**Here are 2 more options**

```
with t as (select date '2016-08-27' as dt) 
select  trunc(add_months(dt,-(month(dt)-1)%3),'MM') 
from    t
;
```

> 2016-07-01

---

```
with t as (select date '2016-08-27' as dt) 
select  add_months(trunc(dt,'YY'),cast((month(dt)-1) div 3 * 3 as INT)) 
from    t
;
```

> 2016-07-01

**For earlier versions**

```
with t as (select '2016-08-27' as dt)
select  printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(dt),(((month(dt)-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1)
from    t
```

> 2016-07-01

**Same, but for today**

```
with t as (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as today)
select  printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(today),(((month(today)-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1) as 
from    t
```

> 2017-04-01

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the quick response.  That would be the ideal answer. the only thing is that the version of hive sql that i'm currently using is an older version and does not support the functions 'add_months' and 'trunc'.   Do you know of a different way to achieve the desired results without using 'add_months' and 'trunc' ?

Comment: Hi Dudu, thank you for your follow up answer.I tried your query for earlier hive sql versions and I do get the correct answer. However, i'm would want my query to not have a hard coded date such as '2016-08-27', because as time passes by for example Q3 comes along, I would want my query to get updated automatically.  Do you know how to do that? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This date is just for the demonstration. Your query should look something like `select printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(dt),(((month(dt)-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1) from orders` (replace `dt` with the relevant column)

Comment: Hi Dudu,  Yes I also replace the '2016-08-27' with my 'date' column. So my query looks as follows: select printf('%04d-%02d-%02d',year(date),(((month(date)-1) div 3) * 3) + 1,1) as date from orders                                      My date field has date values that go as far back as 2013-01-01.  So when I run this query I get the first day of all the quarters as far back as 2013-01-01.  Do you know of a way to tweak the query so that I can only get the first day of the quarter for only the current quarter? so in this case would be April 1 2017

Comment: Thanks so much Dudu. This worked perfectly.  One last thing, do you know how to do the same but for the year? So I want to get the first day of current  year. So it would give January 1st 2017

Comment: Same thing but replace the whole month expression with `1`

Comment: Yes, worked perfectly. Thanks so much for all your help Dudu! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the various date function that Dudu suggested, you can always cast it to string, parse out the month, and use a case statement.  Depending on your version of Hive, you may have to use a simple case instead of searched.

(assuming YYYY-MM-DD)

```
case cast (substring (cast(<date field> as varchar(10)),6,2) as integer)
when between 1 and 3 then 1
when between 4 and 6 then 2
when between 7 and 9 then 3
else 4
end
```

Ugly, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, When i run your query I get the dates with their corresponding quarters. Which is great. For this I also use the following: ceil(month(date)/3.0). Now, how can I get only the first day of the current quarter? So for the current quarter it'll be April 1st.   Note: I do not want to hard code the date because I want it to be flexible as time changes.   Please advise. Thanks!